# NoSuchElementException : Unable to select image from gallery

Tags: appium, nosuchelementexception

I am using nexus 5 to test. How can i choose image from gallery using appium in android.  When i used following code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='Photo
    taken on 13 May 2016 12.50']")).click();
```

I got such Exception:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
> located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING:The
> server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration
> or timeout: 50.56 seconds
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write it with this manner it will select only the first :

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'id of your image')]")).click();
```

With this code you can select any elements you want just put instead of i the element you want starting from 0 for the first one :

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,‌​'id of your image')]")).get(i).click();
```

Comment: Emma thanks for code its working for me but the only problem with this is it is selecting only first image

Comment: Welcome, happy for that ;) ( i'm Emna not Emma haha)

Comment: I have a cool idea  for you to select any elements, try to compile this code and instead i put any element you want for example when i = 0 it's the first elemnt : `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'id of your image')]")).get(i).click();`

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake .

Comment: No problem, did you try the second one ?

Comment: Yes i tried but click() method is undefined for the type Object

Comment: So try to find how to locate elements than use the same logic ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @content-desc='Photo taken on 13 May 2016 12.50']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go by creating xpath!

```
 find_element(xpath: "//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]").click
```

Change your class name accordingly if different.